# Shortening this if condition

Tags: c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

A few days ago I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9013561/) that might be a little unclear. Now I have written code that might illustrate the question better. Please look at the code below first:

```
int d;
d = DateTime.Today.Day;
if (d==1)
{
    hyperlinkButton1.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==2)
{
    hyperlinkButton2.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==3)
{
    hyperlinkButton3.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==4)
{
    hyperlinkButton4.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==5)
{
    hyperlinkButton5.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==6)
{
    hyperlinkButton6.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==7)
{
    hyperlinkButton7.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==8)
{
    hyperlinkButton8.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==9)
{
    hyperlinkButton9.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==10)
{
    hyperlinkButton10.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==11)
{
    hyperlinkButton11.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==12)
{
    hyperlinkButton12.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==13)
{
    hyperlinkButton13.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==14)
{
    hyperlinkButton14.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==15)
{
    hyperlinkButton15.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==16)
{
    hyperlinkButton16.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==17)
{
    hyperlinkButton17.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==18)
{
    hyperlinkButton18.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==19)
{
    hyperlinkButton19.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==20)
{
    hyperlinkButton20.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==21)
{
    hyperlinkButton21.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==22)
{
    hyperlinkButton22.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==23)
{
    hyperlinkButton23.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==24)
{
    hyperlinkButton24.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==25)
{
    hyperlinkButton25.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==26)
{
    hyperlinkButton26.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==27)
{
    hyperlinkButton2.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==28)
{
    hyperlinkButton28.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==29)
{
    hyperlinkButton29.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else if (d==30)
{
    hyperlinkButton30.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
else
{ 
    hyperlinkButton31.Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
```

My question (as a beginner) is this: is there any way in C# to shorten this condition by making the application determine which hyperlinkbutton background it has to change depending on the value of `d`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The array based approach is a good alternative at a general level to the multiple if statements but since this is also tagged as Silverlight, you might be interested in taking advantage of the [FrameworkElement.FindName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx) if you can rely on the convention of naming the HyperlinkButtons with a common prefix.

```
var hyperlinkButton = this.FindName("hyperlinkButton" + DateTime.Now.Day) as HyperlinkButton;
if (hyperlinkButton != null)
{
    hyperlinkButton.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this has really make my life easier ;)

Answer (score 4):

Define an array of the relevant controls, and use the integer to key into the array, remembering that arrays are 0-based and not 1-based.

```
var buttons = new [] {
    hyperlinkButton1,
    hyperlinkButton2,
    hyperlinkButton3,
    hyperlinkButton4,
    hyperlinkButton5,
    hyperlinkButton6,
    hyperlinkButton7,
    hyperlinkButton8,
    hyperlinkButton9,
    // ...
}

//.... 

buttons[DateTime.Today.Day-1].Background=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
switch(d)
{
case 1: doThings(); break;
case 2: doThings2(); break;
case 3:
    doSomeThings();
    doMoreThings();
    break;
default:
    runThingsIfDIsNotListed();
    break;
}
```

etc.